# Few fields are loading after Shared Element Activity Transition

Tags: android, listview, transition, android-transitions

While implementing Shared Element Activity Transition some fields are not loaded and shown blank and after transition is finished everything appears later  even when I set the image at last in the activity using picaso like:-

```
String pos1=json.getString("poster_path");
       Picasso.with(context).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+pos1).into(poster);
```

[image]

I can Post my xml file but i think its of no use I don't know which behaviour causing this glitch any help would be great thanks!

Comment: as your image shows that your adsize is missing from adview try checking that part maybe it is giving that error

Comment: Also provide little code so as to get better understanding of your situation

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HRq2mwgs

Comment: i already solved the issue the problem was i have to provide min height and min width to data show before transition

Comment: if anyone of u need 65 points please post the answer